# Trigonometric interpolation

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis, interpolation

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_interpolation trigonometric interpolation can be calculated as follows:

[image: Trigonometric interpolation]

Now assume we have 6 data points (0, 0.1), (1, 0.3), (2, 0.4), (5, 0.3), (6, 0.2), (7, 0).
We want to interpolate the two missing points at 3 and 4.

[image: Data points]

How can we calculate the two missing points using trigonometric interpolation?

Comment: Hint: Use the given Lagrange type solution in the Wiki article to compute $p(3), p(4)$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused what exactly N is. Is it the number of available samples (eg: 6 in the example) or your sample range (in the example: 7 - 0 + 1 = 8). If it's not too much effort, could you show how to calculate the 4th sample (at index 3)?

Comment: The Wiki article indicates that in your case the polynomial is **not unique**. I suggest you drop the e.g. last data point, then you can apply the formula (and do the same for first, to see the difference between solutions). Another option is to keep the 6 points and add another helper point at say (6.5, 0.1).

Comment: Eliminating one of the points is not a problem. I've tried with the Lagrange manner, but get a totally wrong answer. Assuming we remove the last point, our K = floor(count / 2) = floor(5 / 2) = 2. Is that correct? So our outer sigma is running from 0 to 2K = 4. Hence it will access our y-values at index 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. But our value at position 3 and 4 are missing, What now?

Comment: You mix up $k$ and $x_k$. In order to get the polynomial, forget about the abscissas $x=3$ and $x=4$. If you have a polynomial you can compute $p(3)$ and $p(4)$.

Comment: Ahh, when ignoring the missing samples, things are more clear. My first calculation worked, so will test it in my program now. Thanks.

Comment: Nice to hear. I just coded a small Pascal program using the first five data points and get the values $p(3)=0.42$ and $p(4)=0.38$.

Comment: Any chance you can upload the Pascal code?

Comment: With my example above I now get p(3) = 15.4021 and p(4) = 17.5876, so I'm doing something wrong somewhere. Your Pascal code could really help.

Comment: Yes the code is posted as an answer. You have to normalize the $x$ range to $(0, 2\pi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple answer with the Pascal code mentioned in the comment. Please note that only the missing points are computed not the explicit polynomial:

```
const
  x: array[0..5] of double = (0,   1,   2,   5,   6,   7);
  y: array[0..5] of double = (0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0);

function interpol(u: double): double;
var
  k,m: integer;
  p,f,s: double;
begin
  p := 0.0;
  for k:=0 to 4 do begin
    f := 1.0;
    for m:=0 to 4 do begin
      if m<>k then begin
        s :=   sin(0.25*(u   -x[m])/Pi);
        s := s/sin(0.25*(x[k]-x[m])/Pi);
        f := s*f;
      end;
    end;
    p := p+f*y[k];
  end;
  interpol := p;
end;

var
  u: double;
begin
  u := 3.0;
  writeln('u p(u) = ', u:6:2, interpol(u):10:2);
  u := 4.0;
  writeln('u p(u) = ', u:6:2, interpol(u):10:2);
end.
```

The output is:

```
u p(u) =   3.00      0.42
u p(u) =   4.00      0.38
```

Comment: Ahh, finally got it working, I missed the divide by Pi the entire time. Can't believe my stupid mistake. Thanks gammatester for all your help, I appreciate it.